# Data From Database display to textbox c#

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

Good day Guys. I want to display the value of Townhouse into txthouse after selecting code from the data Thank you guys .

```
DataTable dtRefItem = Common.Common.GetData("SELECT Townhouse FROM County where code= '"+txtbox.text"'"
```

Comment: What `Common.Common.GetData` exactly do? And looks like you need to use `+` after `txtbox.text` like `'" + txtbox.text + "'"`

Comment: Good. What's the question and what have you tried?

Comment: @SonerGönül get the data from the database. I use already that sir i encounter error.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I need to display the value of townhouse when I select the value of code .

Comment: @renats I get what you *want*, but you're not asking a specific question - but could you please explain what your problem is/what error you're getting/what's not working/what you've tried. Just anything that makes this a question which will not be closed for "unclear what you're asking"...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar How can I display the value of Townhouse into textbox using Common.Common.GetData example the data shown to me code 101,102 and 103 each value of code have a Townhouse example paris,malaysia and india if 101 is select i want paris display on my textbox.

Comment: @Renats Thank you - now it's a proper question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataTable` normally contains multiple `DataRow`s. Even if you select only one you need to access that row from it's [`DataTable.Rows`-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx).

```
string townHouse = null;
if(dtRefItem.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    townhouse = dtRefItem.Rows[0].Field<string>("Townhouse");
}
txthouse.Text = townHouse;
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the effort ^^ @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using sql parameters instead of building up the sql command with just strings. this will help limit your exposure to sql injection and is just a good practice to start.